# Click on a like button implemented by iframe doesn't appear on my timeline

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-timeline

I implemented the Facebook "Like" button using iframe into following page:
http://www.atelierdolcevita.be/membres/testxz.php
and when I click on it, my face appears next to it and the "like" does appear in my timeline.

To the contrary, a click on the same "Like" button into following page:
http://www.atelierdolcevita.be/index.php?option=com_content&id=29&lang=fr&task=view
doesn't appear in my timeline. However, my face still appears next to the Like button after clicking on it.

Yet, the documentation of the "Like" button says:

> "Clicking a Like button on a site creates a connection in the graph
>   between the content and the person who clicks the button. Clicking the
>   Like button also publishes an Open Graph Like action, **and displays
>   stories on that person's timeline** and their friends' News Feeds. This
>   story will link back to the site and drive distribution of content."

To demonstrate the problem I added to my testxz.php mentionned above 5 examples of Like buttons referring each to a different URL: examples 1 & 2 work well, examples 3, 4 & 5 do not at all.

Does anybody know why this doesn't work as expected?